# Transform huge CSV files around 2 GB

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, csv, perl

I want to transform huge CSV files and transformation only includes

1. Removing specific columns.
2. Renaming specific columns.

I have implemented a script in node, please find the same below.

```
  for(const m of metadata) {
    try {
      tempm = m;
      const pipelineAsync = promisify(pipeline);
      if(m.path) {
        let dir = `tmp/exports/${exportId}/processed/${m.type}`;
        let fname = `${dir}/${m.sname}`;
        fs.mkdirSync(dir,{recursive: true}, (err) => {
          if(err) throw err;
        });
        await pipelineAsync(
          fs.createReadStream(m.path),
          csv.parse({delimiter: '\t', columns: true}),
          csv.transform((input) => {
            return Object.assign({}, input);
          }),
          csv.stringify({eol: true, record_delimiter: '\r\n', header: true, delimiter: '\t'}),
          fs.createWriteStream(fname, {encoding: 'utf16le'})
        )
      }
    } catch(e) {
      tempm['transformed'] = false;
      console.log(`error with ${m.path}`)
    } finally {
      tArr.push(tempm);
    }
  }
```

this works for the most part, but in case of huge CSV files not all the data is written to the destination file. If the source files contains 1.2GB of data then i see that destination file only contains ~800 MB of data. Since, I process the file in loop I also see that in the same execution flow another file in sequence contains 80MB of data but destination file only contains 35MB of data.

Also, the issue is happening intermittently.

Since, I only want to manipulate the csv columns, is there a more efficient way to do this instead of reading the whole file.

I also read that python / perl are able to handle / process large csv files, may be I can do the processing part as a separate service and then call it from my node.js application.

Also, can anyone please suggest how i can catch such issues where not all data is written to the destination file and pipeline completes in between.

Any help on how to approach this would be really helpfull. Thanks.

Comment: Some ideas that might help you: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/317366/remove-columns-from-a-csv-file/317367

Comment: Well, are you sure you waited until the files got flushed to the disk?

Comment: @Tarik thanks for your reply, how can i identify that? i thought promisifying the pipeline would ensure that.

Comment: Well, yes, that'd be easy in Perl ([Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV))  and Python ([csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)), regardless of how big the file is since CSV is line oriented so it is normally processed by reading one line at a time. The linked libraries are easy to use and well documented, with an abundance of examples around here.

Answer (score 0):

If you have such big files, you should process them using [streams](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html).

Node [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) API allows you to do that.

CSV files are very easy to process using streams.

Comment: Yes, but if I understand your code you are not doing it correctly.
Try to read file until meet [EOL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) then process separate lines and instant push it to write stream.
This is how it should be done.

Comment: thanks for your reply, can you please post an example code or suggest where i can modify my above code?

Comment: first: stop using csv parser, that is consuming whole file.
Try to find one, which is working on streams.
This one looks good: https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-parser

Comment: not sure if i understand it correctly, in the code i posted, i see 1 row returned at a time to `csv.transform`, are you trying to say, the csv parser loads entire file in memory and reads one row at a time?

Comment: I am not sure, I am not able to run your code. I am just assuming that.